# mouse double click is not working quite good 

Tags: windows, mouse, click, media, encoder

I am using the following code to record screen, when recording, when using mouse to double click some item, for example double click a ppt to open it in PowerPoint, it is not very responsive. I have tried and it is much better when using screen recording function of Windows Media Encoder 9. Any ideas what is wrong?

My environment: Windows Vista + Windows Media Encoder 9 + VSTS 2008 + C#. I wrote the following code in the initialization code of a Windows Forms application, and I suspect something wrong with my Windows Forms application?

My code,

```
IWMEncSourceGroup SrcGrp;
IWMEncSourceGroupCollection SrcGrpColl;
SrcGrpColl = encoder.SourceGroupCollection;
SrcGrp = (IWMEncSourceGroup)SrcGrpColl.Add("SG_1");

IWMEncVideoSource2 SrcVid;
IWMEncSource SrcAud;
SrcVid = (IWMEncVideoSource2)SrcGrp.AddSource(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO);
SrcAud = SrcGrp.AddSource(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_AUDIO);

SrcVid.SetInput("ScreenCap://ScreenCapture1", "", "");
SrcAud.SetInput("Device://Default_Audio_Device", "", "");

// Specify a file object in which to save encoded content.
IWMEncFile File = encoder.File;
string CurrentFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
File.LocalFileName = CurrentFileName;
CurrentFileName = File.LocalFileName;

// Choose a profile from the collection.
IWMEncProfileCollection ProColl = encoder.ProfileCollection;
IWMEncProfile Pro;
for (int i = 0; i < ProColl.Count; i++)
{
    Pro = ProColl.Item(i);

    if (Pro.Name == "Screen Video/Audio High (CBR)")
    {
        SrcGrp.set_Profile(Pro);
        break;
    }
}
encoder.Start();
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. But the problem doesn't reside in your code or mine. When I tried to capture screen from Windows Media Encoder application itself I faced the same problem too in about 50% of the sessions. It's evident that it's a bug in WindowsMediaEncoder itself.

George

Comment: Thanks George! Any solutions or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options (from http://www.windowsmoviemakers.net/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1982):

- Enable the MouseKeys Accessibility option, and type + to double-click
- Run the encoder and target application on different machines, and capture a remote desktop session